# How to determine the make of a router from outside the network

Tags: router

I've heard a lot about hackers gaining access to the network by trying default credentials on the router. Let's say an attacker somehow got the router IP of a victim. How would they even know what sort of router it is? Is it even possible to login into your router if you're not connecting to it from inside your network?

Comment: My first thought is to get a telescope and look through a window.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even possible to login into your router if you're not connecting to it from inside your network?

Depends on how the router is configured. Although there is no reason to do this, some routers are still configured to have their administrative interface exposed to the internet by default.

> How would they even know what sort of router it is?

Simply go to the router's administrative interface. Usually, the login page will provide enough clues to let you figure out which router it is.